# How to keyframe object visibility within an action

Tags: animation, mesh, armature, keyframes, dopesheet

I have several objects each with an armature modifier set to the same armature object using vertex groups for influence.  I am trying to hide/show objects during a few frames of an action within the 3d viewport.  I've tried just toggling 'Restrict Viewport Visibility' of the objects in the outliner and adding a keyframe using 'i', but it also hides the armature.  Also, hiding the objects further down the armature chain hides everything else above it.  I've also tried just keyframing the render visibility that results in the same results with Only Render checked under Display of the 3d Viewport Properties.

What I would like to do:

Frame 1 - 5: show everything, but 'Arm-EndSwing'

Frame 6 - 14: hide the object 'Arm-StartSwing', show object 'SlashSprite'

Frame 15: show everything, but 'Arm-StartSwing'

I've done a lot of google searches and forum searches, but cannot figure out a solution.  Might be my lack of animation experience.  Any guidance is appreciated.